# Equalizer resets when MediaPlayer class complete the current music

Tags: android

I have made a music player and its custom equalizer. Equalizer changes the effects very beautifully. But when the `MediaPlayer` class complete one song and start another, my equalizer gets reset.

I have created `Equalizer` object in this way:

```
private static MainActivity f = new MainActivity();
private static Equalizer eq;
```

and in onCreate method I used this:

```
eq = new Equalizer(0, f.mp.getAudioSessionId());//mp is the MediaPlayer object
```

So which way I should proceed to keep my equalizer unchanged until it gets resets manually by user?

Comment: Did you found any solution for this ?